# Using variables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm building a slider control from a dropdown list.

The jQuery UI example uses javascript that looks like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var select = $( "#minbeds" );
    var slider = $( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 6,
    range: "min",
    value: select[ 0 ].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    select[ 0 ].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
    }
});
$( "#minbeds" ).change(function() {
    slider.slider( "value", this.selectedIndex + 1 );
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm basing my work on that, but trying to make it more dynamic - I'm writing a function to turn `select` elements into sliders.  I can guarantee that the `select` elements have options in sorted order, but it isn't clear to me how I can take the var `$select` ($ sign added for distinction as a container of a jQuery object) and use it with other jQuery selectors.

For example, how do I use a variable holding a jQuery object to find the first child of it?  I know something like the following will work:

```
var selected = $('#select-element option:selected').val();
$('#foo').slider({ value: selected });
```

It isn't clear to me, however, how I can take the variable `$select` and get the `option:selected` off of it (or `option:first-child`, `options:last-child`, etc).

In short, I am wondering how I mix typical jQuery selectors with variables that hold jQuery objects.

Comment: [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: For `$('#select-element option:selected')` you can do `$('#select-element').find('option:selected')` so if you have a variable for select element then `$select.find('option:selected')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointy is right, use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Specifically:

```
var selected = $select.find('option:selected').val();
```